# How to return value from a javascript call in Jupyterlab?

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-lab

I am struggling to read clipboard from **jupyterlab**.
My jupyter server is running on a remote instance using docker, so pyperclip and other similar tricks are not working. The idea is to use javascript but I have very limited experience using it. I am able to get the clipboard value and paste it to the log console but not to get back the value to python.

The usual trick using `ipython.notebook.kernel.execute` is not working.

See below the working example. Note that this has to be run in Chrome as afaik Firefox is blocking this feature.

Any suggestion is more than welcome :-)

Patrick

```py
my_js = """
async function paste(input) {
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  return text
}

paste().then((value) => console.log(value));
"""

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript
button = widgets.Button(
    description='Button',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='',
    tooltip='Button',
    icon='check'
)
        
output = widgets.Output()

@output.capture(clear_output=False)
def on_button_clicked(b):
    
    display(Javascript(my_js))

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
display(button, output)

# if you don't want to use ipywidgets, this would also work :
get_ipython().run_cell_magic("javascript", "",my_js)
```

Comment: What is the use case for sending client clipboard content to server? A code doing so would be a big privacy violation red flag kind of thing.

Comment: I just want to copy-paste a pandas DataFrame from Excel to a jupterlab notebook.

Steps:

1. the user copy data from excel 

2. the user click a button "Get from clipboard" in the notebook

3. the data is processed

This works like a charm locally using ´´pandas.read_clipboard´´ function but if the jupyter server runs remotely using docker, the function does not work. In deed this relies on GUI clipboard which is obviously not present on the remote server.

Comment: When you say "working example" what exactly is working?  Did you work out a way to get data from JS to Python not using ipython?